# Eliminating empty space from JavaFX LineChart

Tags: java, css, javafx, linechart

I am trying to create a simple GUI with JavaFX to monitor some system properties. I have a LineChart that I want to show some system information like current CPU load etc. I want to make the linechart small, like the other components in the view. However, there is always empty space below the linechart I can't seem to get rid of:
[JavaFX nodes in VBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcjRx.png)

The chart updates in real time. For the first few ticks the chart looks normal before shrinking: [normal LineChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfwhi.png)

I would like to ensure that the linechart stays the same size throughout and to eliminate the empty space left below so that the linechart does not take a disproportionate amount of space.

I have tried to fiddle with the max, min and pref height settings of the LineChart object to no avail, as well as the padding and Vgrow settings of the parent VBox. I've also tried to remove the padding from the LineChart with inline CSS, but this did not help either. I tried to change the AutoRanging setting in case it had something to do with it but it did not help. I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help would be very much appreciated.

My code to create the linechart:

```
public static LineChart<String, Number> lineChart(int sysInfoCall, int refreshRate) {
    
    if (Objects.isNull(refreshRate)) {
        refreshRate = 500;
    }
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(); 
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.0, 1.0, 1);
    xAxis.setAnimated(false); 
    yAxis.setAnimated(false);
    final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setMaxHeight(50);
    
    
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    // We want the line graph and nothing else
    lineChart.setStyle("-fx-padding:0px");
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    lineChart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
    lineChart.setHorizontalZeroLineVisible(true);
    
    Pane parent = (Pane) xAxis.getParent();
    parent.getChildren().removeAll(xAxis);
    parent = (Pane) yAxis.getParent();
    parent.getChildren().removeAll(yAxis);
    
    lineChart.getData().add(series);
    RTExecutors.executorService(series, sysInfoCall, refreshRate);
    return lineChart;
    
}
```

Comment: When I'm debugging nested views, I set the background of each of them with a different color. This helps me a **lot**.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Why not adjust the `lowerBound` of the `NumberAxis` as data arrives?